# Multiple apps from same codebase in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular-4 application which will have two separate versions, the codebase for both these apps will be almost 70% same. What is the best solution to maintain these applications with common codebase into a single project?

Core verion separates to two app i.e.

1. Public
2. Enterprise

The codebase for both public and enterprise will be 60-70% same.

Comment: I would suggest checking out nx https://nrwl.io/nx. I looked into it a little bit, it seems like it would meet your needs.

Comment: shared components between them.   you can do it in one project, with lazy loading.